# Solidity sha256 returns "0x"

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, remix, geth-debugging

I have a simple smart contract as below. Using go-ethereum-1.8.6 , when i execute `contract.sha.call()` it returns the correct hash value. However, `contract.getSha256.call()` it returns `0x`, did I do something wrong?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

/* Online compiler https://remix.ethereum.org */

contract test{

    address public owner;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function getOwner() external view returns (address) {
        return owner;
    }

    function getSha256() external pure returns (bytes32) {

        bytes32 hash = sha256("12345678");

        return (hash);
    }

    function sha() external pure returns (bytes32) {

        bytes32 hash = sha3("12345678");

        return (hash);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code works for me, if I copy/paste it into remix. So there shouldn't be a problem with your function.

Comment: Yes exactly, it works on remix debugger. But different story if I deploy it on my private net. If I use an older build (bytecode), it works. But with today remix build, it is not. I suspect there may be a bug in recent remix...

Comment: sha3 is deprecated, so maybe it's related. read more here: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1183.
So anyway it's better to use `keccak256`.

Comment: problem is on sha256, sha3 is ok

Comment: It might be that you run into Out-of-Gas for sha256, ripemd160 or ecrecover on a private blockchain. The reason for this is that those are implemented as so-called precompiled contracts and these contracts only really exist after they received the first message (although their contract code is hardcoded). Messages to non-existing contracts are more expensive and thus the execution runs into an Out-of-Gas error. A workaround for this problem is to first send e.g. 1 Wei to each of the contracts before you use them in your actual contracts. This is not an issue on the official or test net.